# Finding the equation of a function

Tags: calculus

> Find the function $y=f(x)$ whose graph is the curve $C$ passing through the point $(2,1)$ and satisfying the following property: each point $(x,y)$ of $C$ is the midpoint of $L(x,y)$ where $L(x,y)$ denotes the segment of the tangent line to $C$ at $(x,y)$ which lies in the first quadrant.

Okay, so with $(2,1)$ being the midpoint of the line segment $L(2,1)$, we have that the $L(2,1)$ must lie on the line $y=2-x/2$. This gives us that that slope of $C$ at $(2,1)$ is $-\frac{1}{2}$. Now I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: You should have mentioned about x- y- coordinate axes and intercept or segment, to be clearer. It took me some time to figure out what you meant, so I made a sketch also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At any point of your curve you have information about the slope of the curve at your point. This means that you have to solve a differential equation.

Suppose $(x_0,y_0) \in C$ is a point of your curve. Then (I skip boring computations) you have that the slope of the curve at $x_0$ is 
$$f'(x_0)=-\frac{y_0}{x_0}$$
so you have to solve the Cauchy problem
$$\left\{ \begin{matrix}
y'=-\frac{y}{x} \\
y(2)=1
\end{matrix} \right.$$
with constraints $y >0, x>0$.

The solution is $f(x)=\frac{2}{x}$

EDIT: How did I find $f'(x_0)=-\frac{y_0}{x_0}$? Here I show my boring (actually there is nothing smart in here) computations.

Let $m= f'(x_0)$. The line $L$ passing through $(x_0,y_0)$ of slope $m$ has equation
$$L: \ \ y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$$
Intersecting $L$ with the $x$ axis we get the point $(-\frac{y_0}{m}+x_0, 0)$.

Intersecting $L$ with the $y$ axis we get the point $(0, y_0-mx_0)$.

So we get the conditions

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}2x_0 = -\frac{y_0}{m}+x_0 \\
2y_0 = y_0-mx_0\end{matrix}\right.$$
which are equivalent to $m= -\frac{y_0}{x_0}$.

Comment: @lamyvista   It is not clear what you want. Tangent at point T of C, cuts the co-ordinate axes at points A and B with AT=TB, is it so? This is trivially true for all curves through the origin.

Comment: @Narasimham what do you mean by AT=TB?

Comment: I introduced the symbols as I could not understand. AB is segment intercepted by x- and y- axes. T is the middle point of AB. T is also point of tangency. It is better if you show in a sketch.

Comment: @ Crostul where did you use (2,1)  being midpoint of L ?

Comment: @Narasimham Using the fact that POints of the curva are midpoints I got $y'=-y/x$. Using $(2,1) \in C$ I got $y(2)=1$. Then I solved the Cauchy problem.

Comment: @Crostul I can justify the slope at x0 being -y0/x0 via an argument using similar triangles like Narasimham, but is there another way to see why this is true?

Answer (score 0):

From the bisecting similar triangles shown

slope of ATB is $ - y^{'}$

$ AT = TB, OS = SB $

$$ x = u = \dfrac {-y}{y^{'}} $$

$$ x dy + y dx =0 $$

Integrating

$$ x \ y = const = 2, $$ using given boundary conditions. It is one of the properties of the rectangular hyperbola.

[image: TgtBisection]

Comment: where is x=u=-y/y' coming from here?

Comment: @lamyvista  $ y/u = \tan TBx = -y^{'}$, and T is mid-point of AB, S is midpoint of OB, x=u.